# PHP webservice cause `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

Tags: php, jquery, web-services

I have a new worker using my traffic website to generate twitter alert. But when I give him the website url the traffic doesnt show and web service doesnt return data. This only happen on this worker PC several others PC's works ok.

I check:

- google chrome and firefox has the latest version
- firewall looks ok because the webservice return the data on a diferent tab.
- pc has windows 7 Ultimate.

[image]

But if I put the link on the webrowser, works ok.

[image]

My pc works ok and load the traffic.

[image]

Comment: **Never** use `async:false` in ajax requests. The warning is telling you something important. It is a terrible practice as it blocks the UI and there is never any need to use it

Comment: That warning can be easily searched but it comes from using synchronous ajax requests that should never be used. Post the code for the ajax and you will see it. It should be refactored

Comment: Not the error ...I'm talking about the yellow warning. If they are using this they really don't know ajax well because it has been a known terrible practice for many years and is probably the root of the error also

Comment: Ok I understand now, That will be a separated problem then. I will just delete the comments.

Comment: So the warning issue is probably part of the error problem

Comment: @charlietfl Dont think so, in the new picture I add, also have same warning and show traffic ok

Comment: doesn't mean it won't work. But what it does it it completely blocks all script execution while that request is being made. That's why it's been known as a terrible practice for many years. it also blocks user interacting with anything in the page. So if request has problems...you get errorrs